# Where and when to populate redux store in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am currently trying to connect my backend database to my redux store and my redux store to my frontend react application. The database and redux are all fine and work well. What I need to know is how to place my "getItems()" function in my react frontend so that my redux store can get the items from the database without breaking my react app. My current approach uses componentDidMount() to time the getItems() function but this causes problems and I would like something further before that. I have considered using the constructor() lifecycle method instead or maybe something inside the mapStateToProps() function but both of these are weirdly deprecated/or have poor documentation. I was wondering if anyone could give me some concrete answer or a real example of something similar.

MusicList.js:

```js
import React, {Component, useState } from "react";
import Items from "./Items";
import AddItem from "./AddItem";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getItems, deleteItem, addItem, toggleItem } from "../actions/itemActions"
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import AppNavbar from "./AppNavbar.js";

class MusicList extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.getItems();
    }

    toggle = (id) => {
        this.props.toggleItem(id)
        console.log(this.props.item.items)
    }

    delItem = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteItem(id)
    }

    addItem = (item, url) => {
        this.props.addItem(item, url)
        console.log(this.props.item.items)
    }

    render() {
        const { items } = this.props.item
        console.log(items)

        return (
            
            <div>

                <div class="sticky-top">
                    {/* <AppNavbar toggle={this.toggle} items={items}/> */}
                    <AddItem addItem={this.addItem}/>
                </div>

                <Items items={items} toggle={this.toggle} delItem={this.delItem} />

            </div>

        )
        
    }

}

MusicList.propTypes = {
    getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deleteItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired, 
    addItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    toggleItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    item: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => (
    {
    item: state.item
    }
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems, deleteItem, addItem, toggleItem})(MusicList);
```

Redux files:

index.js:

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import itemReducer from "./itemReducer";

export default combineReducers({
    item: itemReducer
})
```

types.js:

```js
export const GET_ITEMS = "GET_ITEMS";
export const ADD_ITEM = "ADD_ITEM";
export const DELETE_ITEM = "DELETE_ITEM";
export const TOGGLE_ITEM = "TOGGLE_ITEM";
export const ITEMS_LOADING = "ITEMS_LOADING";
```

itemActions.js:

```js
import axios from "axios"
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, TOGGLE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING } from "./types"

export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch(setItemsLoading());
    axios
    .get("/music_list/items")
    .then(res => dispatch({
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: res.data
    }))
}

export const deleteItem = (id) => dispatch => {
    axios.delete(`/music_list/items/${id}`)
    .then(res => dispatch ({
        type: DELETE_ITEM,
        payload: id
    }))
}

export const addItem = (item, url) => dispatch => {

    console.log(item, url)

    if (url.match(/soundcloud.com/)) {
        let data = {
            "url": url,
            "item": item
        }
        axios
        .post("/music_list/items", data)
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: ADD_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        }))
    }

    else if (url.match(/youtube.com/)) {
        let data = {
            "url": url,
            "item": item
        }
        axios
        .post("/music_list/items", data)
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: ADD_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        }))

        // const regexID = /(?<=v=).*/
        // let id = url.match(regexID)

        // async function newItem(id) {

        //     const item = await titleScrape(id)

        //     // let html = json.html.match(/(?<=url=).{53}/).toString()

        //     let newItem = {
        //         url: item.object.url,
        //         name: item.object.name,
        //         isOpen: false
        //     }

        //     return newItem

        // }

        // newItem(id)
        // .then(item => axios.post("/music_list/items", item).then(res => dispatch({
        //     type: ADD_ITEM,
        //     payload: res.data
        // })))

    }
}

export const toggleItem = (id) => {
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_ITEM,
        payload: id
    }
}

export const setItemsLoading = () => {
    return {
        type: ITEMS_LOADING
    }
}
```

itemReducer.js:

```
import { GET_ITEMS, ADD_ITEM, DELETE_ITEM, TOGGLE_ITEM, ITEMS_LOADING } from "../actions/types"

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ITEMS:
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload,
                loading: false
            };
        case DELETE_ITEM:
            return {
                items: state.items.filter(
                    item => item._id !== action.payload
                )
            }
        case ADD_ITEM:

            console.log(action.payload)

            return {
                items: [...state.items, action.payload]
            }

        case TOGGLE_ITEM:
            return {
                items: state.items.map(item => {
                    if(item._id == action.payload) {
                        item.isOpen = !item.isOpen
                    }
                    else{
                        item.isOpen = false
                    }
                    return item;
                })
            }

        case ITEMS_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

AppNavbar.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Navbar,
    NavbarBrand,
    Nav,
    Button
} from "react-bootstrap";
import './style.css';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class AppNavbar extends Component {

    playTrack = (track_index, items, placeholderTitle, isPlaying, isShuffling) => { 

        console.log(items)
        
        isPlaying = true;

        // playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        
        // Load a new track
        if (isShuffling) {
            track_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)

            items[track_index].this.props.toggle()

            // this.props.toggle(trackIndexToID)

        }
        else {
            items[track_index].this.props.toggle()
        }
        
        // Update details of the track 
        placeholderTitle = this.props.items[track_index].name; 
        
        // Move to the next track if the current finishes playing 
        // using the 'ended' event 

        // items[track_index].addEventListener("ended", nextTrack); 

    }

    playpauseTrack = (track_index, isPlaying, items, placeholderTitle, isShuffling, playTrack, pauseTrack) => { 
        // Switch between playing and pausing 
        // depending on the current state 
        if (!isPlaying) playTrack(track_index, items, placeholderTitle, isPlaying, isShuffling); 
        else pauseTrack(track_index, items, placeholderTitle, isPlaying); 
    }

    pauseTrack = (track_index, items, placeholderTitle, isPlaying) => {

        // Pause the loaded track 
        
        isPlaying = false; 
        
        // Replace icon with the play icon 
        // playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';

        items[track_index].this.props.toggle()
    }
        
    nextTrack = (track_index, isLooping, items, playTrack) => { 
        // Go back to the first track if the 
        // current one is the last in the track list 
        if (track_index < items.length - 1 && !isLooping) {
            track_index += 1; 
        }
        else if (isLooping) {
            track_index = track_index
        }
        else track_index = 0; 
        
        // Load and play the new track 
        playTrack(track_index); 
    } 
        
    prevTrack = (track_index, isLooping, items, playTrack) => { 
        // Go back to the last track if the 
        // current one is the first in the track list 
        if (track_index > 0 && !isLooping) {
            track_index -= 1;
        }
        else if (isLooping) {
            track_index = track_index
        }
        else track_index = items.length; 
        // Load and play the new track 
        playTrack(track_index); 
    }


    // Connect to loop track icon
    loopTrack = (element, isLooping, isShuffling, loopOn, shuffleOff, LoopOff) => {
        if (!isLooping) {
            loopOn(element, isLooping);
            shuffleOff(element, isShuffling);
        }
        else LoopOff(element, isLooping);
    }

    // Connect to shuffle track icon
    shuffleTrack = (element, isLooping, isShuffling, shuffleOn, LoopOff, shuffleOff) => {
        if (!isShuffling) {
            shuffleOn(element, isShuffling);
            LoopOff(element, isLooping);
        }
        else shuffleOff(element, isShuffling);
    }

    loopOn = (element, isLooping) => {
        isLooping = true;
        element.style.opacity = "1"
        console.log("1" + isLooping)
    }

    LoopOff = (element, isLooping) => {
        isLooping = false;
        element.style.opacity = "0.8"
        console.log("2" + isLooping)
    }

    shuffleOn = (element, isShuffling) => {
        isShuffling = true;
        element.style.opacity = "1"
        console.log("3" + isShuffling)
    }

    shuffleOff = (element, isShuffling) => {
        isShuffling = false;
        element.style.opacity = "0.8"
        console.log("4" + isShuffling)
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.items)
        var placeholderTitle = "Who asked (Feat: Nobody)";
        let track_index = 0;
        let isShuffling = false;
        let isLooping = false;
        let isPlaying = false;

        return (

            <Navbar className="Navbar">
                <NavbarBrand id="Logo" href="#home">
                    <img
                    alt=""
                    src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Logo-Smaller.png')}
                    />
                </NavbarBrand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

                    <Nav className="mr-auto">

                        <ul className="navbar-nav">

                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="Title">
                                    Embedded Music
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        
                        </ul>

                    </Nav>

                    <Nav className="mr-auto">

                    <div id="PlayerBox">

                        <ul className="navbar-nav">

                            <li>

                                <header id="Player">
                                    Now Playing:
                                </header>

                                <header id="Player">
                                    {placeholderTitle}
                                </header>

                                <img class="Previous transparent" id="Player" 
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.prevTrack(track_index, isLooping, this.props.items, this.playTrack())}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Previous-smallest.png')}
                                />

                                <img class="playpauseTrack transparent" id="Player"
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.playpauseTrack(track_index, isPlaying, this.props.items, placeholderTitle, isShuffling, this.playTrack(), this.pauseTrack())}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Play-smallest.png')}
                                />
                                
                                <img class="Next transparent" id="Player" 
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.nextTrack(track_index, isLooping, this.props.items, this.playTrack())}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Next-smallest.png')}
                                />

                                <img class="Loop transparent" id="Player"
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.loopTrack(this, isLooping, isShuffling, this.loopOn(), this.shuffleOff(), this.LoopOff())}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Loop-small.png')}
                                />

                                <img class="Shuffle transparent" id="Player" 
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.shuffleTrack(this, isLooping, isShuffling, this.shuffleOn(), this.LoopOff(), this.shuffleOff())}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Shuffle-smallest.png')}
                                />

                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    </Nav>

                    <ul className="navbar-nav">

                        <li>
                            <a href="#Help/FAQ">
                                <Button className="btn btn-secondary Button">Help/FAQ</Button>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#Contact">
                                <Button className="btn btn-secondary Button">Contact</Button>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#Donate">
                                <Button className="btn btn-secondary Button">Donate</Button>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}

AppNavbar.propTypes = {
    toggle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}


export default AppNavbar;
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` is the correct lifecycle method to issue side-effects to fetch/load data. What isn't working? What is "breaking the app"? Is `this.props.item` or `this.props.item.items` undefined? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @DrewReese This is the current problem with componentDidMount: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944530/child-component-in-react-prevents-parent-component-from-importing-redux-store

It works very well with my items.js component but breaks when I also add my AppNavbar.js component, which is why I am trying to fetch the data even further back in the timeline.

Comment: Ok. Seems like you are passing `undefined` state from your redux store. Can you include your redux/reducer code and redux provider in your question?

Comment: @DrewReese Sure but I'm not sure they will be of much help, they all worked well as long as the appNavbar.js component was commented out, it's only when it is connected that it somehow makes the state empty in react.

Comment: Does `getItems` successfully return a valid `payload` in the action? Do also notice a state mutation in your reducer on the `TOGGLE_ITEM` action. If the code is working until you add `AppNavbar` then can you include *that* component code as well then?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes getItems() returns a valid payload, I am sure of it. I will post the AppNavbar aswell. The "this.props.items" call is where I get a undefined error like in the other question I posted above. My theory is is that this undefined error seizes the MusicList.js component and thus the component never really mounts and it never runs getItems() to create the redux store and make the react state. So In a paradoxical loop the program never makes the store and because it never makes the store it cant run the code to make the store... 1/2

Comment: 2/2 But this dosen't explain how the Items.js component does it with no problem. So I decided to just move the getItems function earlier instead.

Comment: So when `AppNavbar` is commented out the code 100% works without issue? If you simply render `AppNavbar` ***and do nothing else*** does it render and not have issue(s) until you interact with the UI, or does it immediately throw an error or something?

Comment: @DrewReese It immediately throws an error calling this.props.items (in AppNavbar.js) as undefined with this message at the bottom: "This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production."

Comment: Your callbacks in `AppNavbar` invoke immediately, and I suspect they end up calling `this.props.toggle` but in your snippets *that* line is commented out and you instead call something like `items[track_index].this.props.toggle()` which doesn't look right at all. If you comment out any of the JSX in `AppNavbar` that "toggles" anything does it still immediately throw error?

Comment: @DrewReese I think you are absolutely right on the toggle problem. I've changed them to "this.props.toggle(items[track_index].id)" And I still get the "items" undefined error. I have gone ahead and commented out the appNavbar function and the buttons that calls them and my problem is solved. I think I will try and recreate the AppNavbar component from semi scratch because clearly I have messed something up internally. Thank you very much, I would upvote if I could.

Comment: Think you could create a simple codesandbox that reproduces the issue? Mock the API response data and simply try passing the `items` array around.

Comment: I will consider it, It will take a few days for me to play around with the component. Once it's resolved I will update both questions.

Comment: Ok, feel free to @ me if you like.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for the help I fixed the problem with your aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok multiple things were messed up in my AppNavbar.js component. I was calling calling the functions in my JSX instead of referencing them which would run them before the state was finished and break my program. Here is the updated program. I also moved everything to the state. Thank you @DrewReese for the valuable help.

```
class AppNavbar extends Component {

    state = {
        placeholderTitle: "Who asked (Feat: Nobody)",
        track_index: 0,
        isShuffling: false,
        isLooping: false,
        isPlaying: false
    };

    playTrack = () => { 
        console.log(this.state.track_index)
        this.state.isPlaying = true;

        // playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-pause-circle fa-5x"></i>';
        
        // Load a new track
        
        if (this.state.isShuffling) {
            this.setState({
                track_index: Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.items.length)
            })

            this.props.toggle(this.props.items[this.state.track_index]._id)

        }
        else {
            this.props.toggle(this.props.items[this.state.track_index]._id)
        }
        
        // Update details of the track 
        this.setState({
            placeholderTitle: this.props.items[this.state.track_index].name
        })

        console.log(this.props.items[this.state.track_index])
        
        // Move to the next track if the current finishes playing 
        // using the 'ended' event 

    }

    playpauseTrack = () => { 
        // Switch between playing and pausing 
        // depending on the current state 
        if (!this.state.isPlaying) this.playTrack(); 
        else this.pauseTrack(); 
    }

    pauseTrack = () => {

        // Pause the loaded track 
        this.setState({
            isPlaying: false
        })
        
        // Replace icon with the play icon 
        // playpause_btn.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"></i>';

        this.props.toggle(this.props.items[this.state.track_index]._id)
    }
        
    nextTrack = () => { 
        // Go back to the first track if the 
        // current one is the last in the track list

        // much preferred imo. very easy to reason about, probably more performant
        const settingTempState = () => {
            // this acts as a sort of "draft" version of the next state
            const tempState = { ...this.state }
    
            // you use it throughout the function instead of this.state
    
            if (tempState.track_index < this.props.items.length - 1 && !tempState.isLooping) {
                tempState.track_index = tempState.track_index + 1
            }
            else if (tempState.isLooping) {
                tempState.track_index = tempState.track_index
            }
            else { 
                tempState.track_index = 0
            }

            console.log(tempState.track_index)
    
            // only one state update occurs
            this.setState(tempState, () => this.playTrack())
        }

        settingTempState()

        console.log(this.state.track_index)
        
        // Load and play the new track
    } 
        
    prevTrack = () => { 
        // Go back to the last track if the 
        // current one is the first in the track list 

        const settingTempState = () => {
            // this acts as a sort of "draft" version of the next state
            const tempState = { ...this.state }
    
            // you use it throughout the function instead of this.state
    
            if (tempState.track_index > 0 && !tempState.isLooping) {
                tempState.track_index = tempState.track_index - 1
            }
            else if (tempState.isLooping) {
                tempState.track_index = tempState.track_index
            }
            else { 
                tempState.track_index = this.props.items.length - 1
            }
    
            // only one state update occurs
            this.setState(tempState, () => this.playTrack())
        }

        settingTempState()

        console.log(this.state.track_index)

        // Load and play the new track 
    }


    // Connect to loop track icon
    loopTrack = () => {
        if (!this.state.isLooping) {
            this.loopOn();
            this.shuffleOff();
        }
        else this.LoopOff();
    }

    // Connect to shuffle track icon
    shuffleTrack = () => {
        if (!this.state.isShuffling) {
            this.shuffleOn();
            this.LoopOff();
        }
        else this.shuffleOff();
    }

    loopOn = () => {
        this.setState({
            isLooping: true
        })
        console.log("1" + this.state.isLooping)
    }

    LoopOff = () => {
        this.setState({
            isLooping: false
        })
        console.log("2" + this.state.isLooping)
    }

    shuffleOn = () => {
        this.setState({
            isShuffling: true
        })
        console.log("3" + this.state.isShuffling)
    }

    shuffleOff = () => {
        this.setState({
            isShuffling: false
        })
        console.log("4" + this.state.isShuffling)
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.items)

        return (

            <Navbar className="Navbar">
                <NavbarBrand id="Logo" href="#home">
                    <img
                    alt=""
                    src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Logo-Smaller.png')}
                    />
                </NavbarBrand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">

                    <Nav className="mr-auto">

                        <ul className="navbar-nav">

                            <li>
                                <a href="#" className="Title">
                                    Embedded Music
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        
                        </ul>

                    </Nav>

                    <Nav className="mr-auto">

                    <div id="PlayerBox">

                        <ul className="navbar-nav">

                            <li>

                                <header id="Player">
                                    Now Playing:
                                </header>

                                <header id="Player">
                                    {this.state.placeholderTitle}
                                </header>

                                <img class="btnPrev Previous transparent" id="Player" 
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.prevTrack}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Previous-smallest.png')}
                                />

                                <img class="btnPlayPauseTrack playpauseTrack transparent" id="Player"
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.playpauseTrack}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Play-smallest.png')}
                                />
                                
                                <img class="btnNext Next transparent" id="Player" 
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.nextTrack}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Next-smallest.png')}
                                />

                                <img class="btnLoop Loop transparent" id="Player" style={{opacity: this.state.isLooping ? "1" : "0.8"}}
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.loopTrack}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Loop-small.png')}
                                />

                                <img class="btnShuffle Shuffle transparent" id="Player" style={{opacity: this.state.isShuffling ? "1" : "0.8"}}
                                alt=""
                                onClick={this.shuffleTrack}
                                src={require('D:/Parrot/Desktop/Dev/Duplicate/Embedded_Music_Player/client/src/images/Shuffle-smallest.png')}
                                />

                            </li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    </Nav>

                    <ul className="navbar-nav">

                        <li>
                            <a href="#Help/FAQ">
                                <Button className="btn btn-secondary Button">Help/FAQ</Button>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#Contact">
                                <Button className="btn btn-secondary Button">Contact</Button>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#Donate">
                                <Button className="btn btn-secondary Button">Donate</Button>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        )
    }
}

AppNavbar.propTypes = {
    toggle: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}


export default AppNavbar;
```